# Error in creating list

Tags: android-listview

I am new to android and i have a Error creating list....... What is the Error? some one help me out........ I am using api18.........

package com.example.personalinformationmanagement;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    String list[] = {"PersonalTask", "PersonaFileInformation","WeaklyReports", "Remainder"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1));
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.ListActivity#onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView, android.view.View, int, long)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String choice = list[position];
        try{
        Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.example.personalinformationmanagement." +choice);
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ourClass);
        startActivity(i);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();            
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: please also post error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all ensure that listview id in your activity_main.xml equals to "android:id="@android:id/list".
In code change line

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list));
```

If you want to manipulate with listView use:

```
ListView myListView = getListview();
```